# Yii2 - Pass ActiveDataProvider from View to another controller

Tags: gridview, controller, yii2, parameter-passing, action

I have an Index view with a GridView showing a list of date related items. I also have another link on that view, which I intend to populate a calendar widget showing all the row items on a calendar instead of a table.

The user may have set one or more filters. How can I pass the ActiveDataProvider variable that comes into the View to another action so that I may populate the calendar widget.

EDIT:

Currently I tested as follows:

VIEW:

```
<?= Html::a('Test', ['calendar', 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider], [ 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', ]) ?>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function actionCalendar($dataProvider)
    {
        print_r($dataProvider->getModels());die("");
    }
```

I get an error...

> Bad Request (#400)
>
> Invalid data received for parameter "dataProvider".

Answer (score 1):

In controller You can use  redirect

```
return Yii::$app->response->redirect(array('yourController/yourAction',
      'yourParam'=>$yourDataProvider));
```

Make sure the the `yourParam` name match the param name in the external action

In view you can simply use an url.

Add the proper `use` if needed

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
```

this sample is for `<a>` tag

```
<a  href="<?= Url::to(['yourController/yourAction', 
            'yourParam' =>  $yourDataProvider ]) ?>"  '>your anchor text</a>
```

In your case you are calling the controller/action by a view link  try this

```
   <?= Html::a('Test', ['calendar', 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider], 
        [ 
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
            'method' => 'post',
        ],
  ]) ?>
```

Comment: Show the code for the controller/action receiver..please

Comment: I had actually tried post method as well earlier and it gave me the same error. In reality, I solved my final requirement by simply creating a link with the SearchModel's GET parameters. Although, I was still interested in a solution where we could pass complex variables to controller from view. Perhaps, it defeats the purpose of MVC (dunno)